# the app references non-public selectors in payload addMatches: (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store-connect, xcode5

As of XCode5/ios7, when validating my application I am now getting a validation warnings on a selector that is automatically generated by xcode. After searching my source code, i don't see anything alarming. Has anyone else ran into this before?

```
@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMatchesObject:(Match *)value;
- (void)removeMatchesObject:(Match *)value;
- (void)addMatches:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMatches:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addNotificationsObject:(Notification *)value;
- (void)removeNotificationsObject:(Notification *)value;
- (void)addNotifications:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeNotifications:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

**UPDATE**

Surprisingly enough, I refactored my code to use addMatchesObject: instead of addMatches, and the validation warnings went away. ....dafuq?

Comment: What is User a subclass of? Seems like whatever it is, it has a private matches ivar that you inadvertently collided with.

Comment: @EricLeaf just a standard autogenerated `@interface User : NSManagedObject`

Answer (score 0):

It is alarming. I had to refactor a load of my core data selectors as well.

Until I did this, my updates for that app were taking much longer in app review than my other apps, so its worth doing.